# Android - the app keyboard freezes some times

Tags: android, performance, android-keypad

I am developing a chat app using XMPP and asmack library. The issue I am facing is while typing in a chat message, the keyboard some times freezes and then the typed in letters. This is not happening all the time and is happening only twice in ten times...But Still I believe this will be annoying to the users. Any idea how to avoid this or what might cause this issue so that I can concentrate on that particular area in Android....

Any help would be great. Thanks